# Problem comprehending “push the relatively small, for example the impact of the munition megaton class”

Tags: comprehension

[Example](http://finance.yahoo.com/news/russian-doctor-military-sciences-says-181400470.html):

> "Geologists believe that the Yellowstone supervolcano could explode at any moment. There are signs of growing activity there. Therefore it suffices to **push the relatively small, for example the impact of the munition megaton class** to initiate an eruption. The consequences will be catastrophic for the United States, a country just disappears," he said, according to a translation by Sydney Morning Herald.

I don't think I can make grammatical sense of that part on my own. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That’s hard for anyone to understand! The original Russian is:

> Поэтому достаточно относительно небольшого **толчка**, например удара боеприпаса мегатонного класса, чтобы инициировать извержение.
> <sub>Source: [vpk-news.ru, *Nuclear Riot*](http://vpk-news.ru/articles/24405)</sub>

“толчка” has been translated as “push”, which is basically correct, but it has [other meanings](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0). The word order of the SMH translation is also no help to understanding. Better translations might be:

> Therefore, a relatively small **{ shock / jolt / kick }** would be sufficient to initiate the eruption. For example, the impact of a megaton-class munition.

A “megaton-class munition” is just an explosive with a yield at or in excess of 1 megaton, such as a [B83 nuclear bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B83_nuclear_bomb), which has a variable yield up to 1.2 megatons (meaning the explosive force can be made equivalent to 1.2 million tons of TNT, though the B83 itself weighs only 2.4 tons).